# LINQ to loop and get the results for the same records

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, linq

Lets say i have two tables with almost the same structure

**TableFrom**

```
ID         bigint
Username   nvarchar
Password   nvarchar
Name       nvarchar
```

**TableTo**

```
ID         bigint
Username   nvarchar
Password   nvarchar
```

Now i want to generate an Insert into SQL query ( using parameters ) but only for those fields who are the same in both tables. ( *id, username, password* )

I thought about reading those two table structure queries into dataTable and after that loop with LINQ to get array of fields which are the same in bot tables ?

```
Dim dtFrom as new datatable
dim dtTo as NEW dataTable

dtTo = _LoadAvaliableToFields()
dtFrom = _loadAvailableFromFields()
```

How would that LINQ go ?

After that i need to add the Insert query to database using parameters. Is there any simpler way to do this ?

Comment: I'd suggest how to write the proper SQL statement first, then think about using LINQ. LINQ is **not** a replacement for SQL. In fact, if you are using words like `table` and `insert` it's a very-very strong indication that you should be writing a SQL statement, not a LINQ query to work with entities. BTW, since LINQ is a query language it has no modification functionality. It's the ORM that provides this

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This example is been writen here on this forum from my head. I have around 255 tables which needs to pass this problem in my program.

Comment: The basis of what you need is an `Intersect` query (using field names): find elements that are common to two sequences.

Answer (score 0):

Using query syntax the "select" query would be very similar to a SQL query:

```
Dim query = 
    From idFrom In TableFrom _
    Join idTo In TableTo _
    On     New With {Key .ID = idFrom.ID, Key .U = idFrom.Username, Key .P = idFrom.Password} _
    Equals New With {Key .ID = idTo.ID,   Key .U = idTo.Username,   Key .P = idTo.Password} _
    Select idFrom
```

To do an *insert* you'd need to add objects to the appropriate collections in the context, then call `SaveChanges`.

I would note that a direct SQL query would be more efficient:

```sql
INSERT INTO {destination}
SELECT f.ID,f.Username,f.Password
FROM TableFrom f
INNER JOIN TableTo t 
ON f.ID = t.ID AND f.Username = t.Username AND f.Password = t.Password
```

Comment: Sir the main problem here is. How to get the result of the fields which contain the both tables. I cant write it manually those fields. I need a script which will generate me the same fields

Comment: OK I misunderstood your problem.  I would not use Linq.  Linq is meant to be strongly-typed, while you need to choose columns dynamically.  I would use a DataTable to dynamically choose the common fields, then build the INSERT command dynamically as well.